# How to fix Flutter dropdown button overflow issue?

Tags: dart, flutter, overflow, dropdown

I create a Flutter Form and I build a dropdown button with flutter. I am losing local son data into dropdown. Some of my items in dropdown button is long. I use SafeArea and ListView and I am getting overflow on right.

partial solution not mentioned in the other question, and I get the answer here.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
 // TODO: BUILD RUN
        return new Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            body: new SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: new Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: new ListView(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 32.0),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //TODO: CURRENCY 
                        new FormField<String>(
                          builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                            return InputDecorator(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'CHOOSE CURRENCY',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.green.shade700),
                                errorText: state.hasError ? state.errorText : null,
                              ),
                              isEmpty: _mySelectedCurrency == '',
                              child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                  value: _mySelectedCurrency,
                                  isDense: true,
                                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _mySelectedCurrency = newValue;
                                      state.didChange(newValue);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  items: _itemsName,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          validator: (val) {
                            return val != '' ? null : 'Choose Currency...';
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - DropdownButton overflow in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032262/flutter-dropdownbutton-overflow-in-listview)

Comment: yes its similar... And seems GitHub issues not resolved yet. Problem is that work around will not going to fix for me, the dropdown menu item will be more than 3 line sometimes... Looking for fixed and closed solution, thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Though I have flagged the question as [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032262/flutter-dropdownbutton-overflow-in-listview), a partial solution not mentioned in the other question is to use the `isExpanded` property for `DropDownButton`.

```
              child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working without getting any error or overflow. But I need to ask. What do you mean "partial solution"?

Comment: Well, reading the last comment in the Github issue, I couldn't but agree with the poster. It works but may not work in all situations.

Comment: thanks, still looking final solution, and I modify my menu item so currently I have no problem...

Comment: That indeed helped me a lot ! Thanks

Comment: also works on the `DropdownButtonFormField`

Answer (score 9):

In most cases, in addition to the expanded, it is also good to make it ellipsized.. steps 1 and 2. If it's not ellipsized it will make it wrap to next line and if the component doesn't support multiples lines it will truncated the text.

```
DropdownButton(
    isExpanded: true, //Step 1
    items: [
        new DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text("Long text that overflow the size.. wrapped or ellipsized", 
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),  //Step 2
        ),
    ],
    onChanged: (val) { }
)
```